# Disabling ALL USB-ports

Tags: usb, hardware, pi-3

I have a problem with disabling any USB ports with the command:
`sudo sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/buspower"` Nothing happens at all, though the content of the file IS changed to 0x0 or 0x1.

When entering

```
sudo sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/buspower"
```

the LED of the webcam I'm trying to turn off flashes of and on for about half a second so it is affecting the USB ports in some way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/49440/power-usb-device-over-raspberry-pi-gpio-pin/49442#49442) is a related question where we discussed an app that allows control of USB ports from the command-line.

Comment: Thank you! The small C-program did it, totally missed that. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Because it's impossible to disable the usb power, I've used udev rules and a script installed in `/usr/local/sbin` (tested on Raspberry PI3)

**The script :**

```
 \#!/bin/bash  
 ROOTUSB=/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1  
 \#Exceptions network device  
 EXC="1-1.1 1-1:1.0"  
 for host in $ROOTUSB/*  
 do  
if [ -f $host/authorized ];then  
disable=1  
\# Parse exception to allow them to be enabled (network...)  
for device in $EXC  
do  
\# If host ending equal excetion =>> dont change state  
[[ $host =~ \/$device$ ]] && disable=0  
done  
\#Otherwise change state ==> disable  
if [ $disable = 1 ];then  
\#USB host to disable  
echo 0 >  $host/authorized  
fi  
fi  
done
```

**The udev rules**

```
 /etc/udev/rules.d/10-disableusb.rules  
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", RUN+="/usr/local/sbin/disable-usb.sh"
```

**Refresh udev rules**

```
udevadm control --reload-rules
```

Plug in a storage usb device, now, you are not allowed to enumerate filesystems

Comment: please read the other answer! There is a way of controlling the power and it's by using the feature that check if the USB port is shorten or not, check https://github.com/codazoda/hub-ctrl.c