# Shut off all USB ports

Tags: pi-4

Is there a command that shuts off power to both USB 2.0 ports on the Pi 4?

Bonus points if the command does not disable the USB 3.0 or Ethernet.

Comment: It seems that this could be the solution for individually on/off control: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/49442/111436 and this: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/8652/111436 for on/off for the USB hub. Both solutions worked on previous Pis so might be possible that they still work for the Pi 4.

Comment: Is Ethernet still tied to USB in the pi 4 like in earlier pi's?

Comment: According to (https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=813383), `sudo ./hub-ctrl -h 0 -P 2 -p 0 ; sleep 3; sudo ./hub-ctrl  -h 0 -P 2 -p 1` should turn off USB power, wait three seconds, and turn it on again, without harming ethernet -- however, it was tested on a Raspberry Pi 2B.