# USB power stay on after software shutdown?

Tags: usb, power-supply

When the RPi4 does a soft shutdown, it appears to leave power on to the USB ports. Is there a way to have the USB ports power off with the RPi?

I’m building a project with a Waveshare touchscreen that gets power through the USB for the touchscreen, so it’s not shutting off when the RPi executes a shutdown.

TIA
Michael

Comment: this has been asked here before

Comment: In that case, why not tell me where? Otherwise this is not a useful answer - I have searched, and could not get the information I am looking for.

Comment: it's not an answer ... answers are posted below ... i remember seeing this before ... I'll try to find it

Comment: search `shut off usb power`

Comment: Thanks, that does help. Funny how specific your search terms need to be sometimes. Anyway, one topic (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105686/shut-off-all-usb-ports) may contain a sofware solution, but I'll have to try it. If it does work, then I'll need to figure out how to incorporate it into the shutdown scripts.  Ah well - one step at a time. I'll wait until I've tested solutions before claiming there's an answer...